# Is Red Code unique per derivative instrument

Tags: derivatives, cds

Does RED Code (="Markit Reference Entity Database Code") uniquely identify the derivative that has been traded?

Is it possible to get a derivative's ISIN code from RED Code?

Answer (score 2):

What RED Code does is to uniquely identify the **underlying reference entity** of a **CDS contract**. Hence it’s name.

Comment: So it identifies the underlaying, but it does not identifies derivative. Is that correct?